# Problem with Auto Generated Dropdownlist column in Gridview ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
protected void gridChamCong_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        List<DateTime> NgayNghi = new List<DateTime>();
        NgayNghi = oNgayNghi.load_ListNgayNghi();
        int ngayle = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = txtCongChuan.Text;                
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = txtCongChuan.Text;                
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = txtCongChuan.Text;
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = txtCongChuan.Text;

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtCa3 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txtCa3.ID = "txtCa3";
            txtCa3.Text = "0";
            txtCa3.Width = 30;
            e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtCa3); 

            int songay = 0;
            DateTime denngay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateDenNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
            DateTime tungay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTuNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
            songay = ((int)(denngay - tungay).TotalDays) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < songay; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ddlKiHieuChamCong = new DropDownList();
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.ID = "ddlKiHieuChamCong";
                System.Data.DataTable ddlKyHieu = new System.Data.DataTable();
                ddlKyHieu = oKyHieuChamCong.GetDataDDLKyHieuChamCong();
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.DataSource = ddlKyHieu;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.DataTextField = ddlKyHieu.Columns[1].ColumnName;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.DataValueField = ddlKyHieu.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.DataBind();
                //ddlKiHieuChamCong.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlKiHieuChamCong_SelectedIndexChanged;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.Enabled = true;
                ddlKiHieuChamCong.EnableViewState = true;
                DateTime ngayxet = tungay.AddDays(i);
                if (ngayxet.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || ngayxet.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    ddlKiHieuChamCong.SelectedIndex = 9;
                else if (NgayNghi.Exists(x => x.Date == ngayxet.Date))
                {
                    ddlKiHieuChamCong.SelectedIndex = 5;
                    ngayle++;
                }
                else
                    ddlKiHieuChamCong.SelectedIndex = 0;
                e.Row.Cells[7].Text = ngayle+"";
                e.Row.Cells[i + 8].Controls.Add(ddlKiHieuChamCong);
            }
        }
    }
protected void btnTao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DateTime> NgayNghi = new List<DateTime>();
        NgayNghi = oNgayNghi.load_ListNgayNghi();
        if (gridChamCong.Columns.Count > 0)
            gridChamCong.Columns.Clear();

        BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
        bfield.HeaderText = "Id";
        bfield.DataField = "ID";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(bfield);

        BoundField tName = new BoundField();
        tName.HeaderText = "Nhân sự";
        tName.DataField = "Tên Nhân Viên";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tName);

        TemplateField tCountDate = new TemplateField();
        tCountDate.HeaderText = "Ngày công";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tCountDate);

        TemplateField tNgayLuongHeSo = new TemplateField();
        tNgayLuongHeSo.HeaderText = "LHS";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tNgayLuongHeSo);

        TemplateField tNgayLuongCanBan = new TemplateField();
        tNgayLuongCanBan.HeaderText = "LCB";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tNgayLuongCanBan);

        TemplateField tNgayAnGiuaCa = new TemplateField();
        tNgayAnGiuaCa.HeaderText = "AGC";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tNgayAnGiuaCa);

        TemplateField tNgayCa3 = new TemplateField();
        tNgayCa3.HeaderText = "Ca3";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tNgayCa3);

        TemplateField tNgayPhep = new TemplateField();
        tNgayPhep.HeaderText = "Lễ/Phép";
        gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tNgayPhep);

        int songay = 0;
        DateTime denngay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateDenNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
        DateTime tungay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTuNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
        if (denngay >= tungay)
        {
            songay = ((int)(denngay - tungay).TotalDays) + 1;
            int congchuan = connectDatabase.BusinessDaysUntil(tungay, denngay,NgayNghi);
            txtCongChuan.Text = congchuan.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < songay; i++)
            {
                TemplateField tDate = new TemplateField();
                tDate.HeaderText = (tungay.AddDays(i)).ToString("dd/MM");
                gridChamCong.Columns.Add(tDate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lbLoi.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lbLoi.Text = "Đến ngày phải lớn hơn Từ ngày";
        }

        BindGridChamCong();
    }

    //----------------------------------------CHẤM CÔNG------------------------------

    protected void btnLuu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime denngay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateDenNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
        DateTime tungay = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTuNgay.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
        DateTime ngaytao = DateTime.ParseExact(dateNgayTao.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
        //get id phiếu lớn nhất
        txtPhieuID.Text = oPhieuChamCong.getMaxID() + "";
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //Insert Phiếu chấm công
        oPhieuChamCong.insertPhieuChamCong(txtTenPhieu.Text, Int32.Parse(ddlDonvi.SelectedValue), tungay, denngay, 1, Int32.Parse( connectDatabase.ID_Nhanvien)
            , ngaytao, txtGhiChu.Text);            
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //Insert phiếu chấm công tổng
        for (int i = 0; i < gridChamCong.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string mang = "";
            int ngaycongtinhluong = Int32.Parse(txtCongChuan.Text.Trim());
            int angiuaca = ngaycongtinhluong;
            int lhs = ngaycongtinhluong;
            int lcb = ngaycongtinhluong;
            int phep = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < gridChamCong.Columns.Count-8 ; j++)
            {
                DateTime ngayxet = tungay.AddDays(j);
                if (ngayxet.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && ngayxet.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                     System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList  ddlChamcong = new  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ();
                    int slcontrol = gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[j + 8].Controls.Count;
                    ddlChamcong = ( System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[j+8].FindControl("ddlKiHieuChamCong");
                    string congngay = ddlChamcong.Text.Trim();
                    mang = mang + ngayxet.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "," + congngay;
                    mang = mang + ";";
                    if (!congngay.Equals("P") && !congngay.Equals("X") && !congngay.Equals("L"))
                    {
                        lhs--;
                        angiuaca--;
                        ngaycongtinhluong--;
                        lcb--;
                    }
                    else if (congngay.Equals("P") || congngay.Equals("L"))
                    {
                        lhs--;
                        angiuaca--;
                        ngaycongtinhluong--;
                        phep++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtECustCode = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("txtCa3");
            int ca3 = Int32.Parse(txtECustCode.Text);
            int id_phieu = Int32.Parse(txtPhieuID.Text.Trim());
            int id_nv = Int32.Parse(gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);

            oPhieuChamCongTong.insertPhieuChamCongTong(id_phieu, id_nv 
                , lhs, lcb, angiuaca, ngaycongtinhluong,ca3, phep, mang, "");
        }            
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //ghi log
        connectDatabase.insert_Log("updatePhieuChamCong", connectDatabase.TenTK, "Cập nhật/Thêm phiếu chấm công  "+ txtPhieuID.Text + txtTenPhieu.Text + " Đơn vị: " + ddlDonvi.Text, DateTime.Now);

        Response.Redirect("~/Quanly/ChiTietChamCong.aspx");
    }
```

I have a problem when I click `btnLuu_Click`, `gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("txtCa3")`  and 
`gridChamCong.Rows[i].Cells[j+8].FindControl("ddlKiHieuChamCong")`  return null. If I uncomment `ddlKiHieuChamCong.AutoPostBack = true` , When I change selected index of `ddlKiHieuChamCong`, all controls in columns generated become null.

Inside the `OnRowDataBound` event of the GridView, the process of adding controls like TextBox, DropDownLists

Comment: You need to share the only code which is relevant to the problem you are facing. Dumping entire code behind of the page will not help. Can you also point out which line in the code gives you null?

Comment: You should add DropDownList to the gridview in aspx only. Adding controls at runtime has its own set of complexity which causes the issues like this

Comment: so, how to auto generate dropdownlist column with number column belong to from date, to date?

Comment: Is `oKyHieuChamCong.GetDataDDLKyHieuChamCong()` is same for all the dropdownlists?

Comment: yes, it's the same

Comment: Then you can Have the DropDownList in template column in gridview in aspx and bind the DropDownList of each row in RowDataBound event of the gridview.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/use-dropdownlist-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: but this way cannot add different number of column belong to from date, to date.

Comment: as example, January has 31 days, February has 29 days. How can I generate 31 or 29 columns by code in aspx?